# Verifying Distribution Equivalence for Fourier Series Expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

In my lecture notes, given a periodic distribution $T \in (C_{per}^\infty([-\pi,\pi]^n))'$, the Fourier coefficients are defined by
$$\hat T(m) = T({1 \over (2\pi)^n}e^{-i m \cdot x}),$$
for $m \in \Bbb Z^n$. I am then asked to verify that the formal series
$$\sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} \hat T(m) e^{i m \cdot x}$$
defines a distribution which agrees with $T$.

My attempt is given in an answer below.

Thanks! :) Sam

Comment: Yeah, that was what I thought (see final paragraph). Unfortunately, I'm unable to make any more progress...

Comment: $\hat T(m)$ here are not distributions, they are numbers. The distribution is $e^{im\cdot x}$, which is multiplied by a constant $\hat T(m)$ and then applied to a test function.

Comment: $T$ is applied to a function $x\to \frac{1}{2^n\pi^n}e^{-imx}$

Comment: Ah ok, so $\hat T(m) = T({1 \over (2\pi)^n}e^{-i m \cdot x})$ is the value of $T$ applied to $e^{-im \cdot x}$, divided by $(2\pi)^n$?

Comment: Sorry, I sent my message before yours came up! Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow*. If I'm still stuck, ok if I ask you again? [*I'm in the UK, so nearly 11pm now.]

Comment: Sure, if you still have any questions, ask then when you have time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still stuck on this! Just can't get the notation right! Is it ok if you say write out the first half of the argument (as an answer?)? This *should* get me started.

Comment: Let's do it another way: you edit the original answer with some sort of a draft of your solution - and then we identify where you're getting stuck and how to overcome the problem.

Comment: I have done so. It's really tying me up in knots! :( =P

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure I've got it right now (fingers crossed =P!), so I've put it as an answer. The key bit that was getting me was that I didn't know what the distribution $e^{i m \cdot x}$ meant, but then I remembered(/think) that it is just shorthand for the distribution given by integrating against $e^[i m \cdot x}$ as a kernel. If you could check the answer, then I'd be most appreciative! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all we use the definition given:

$$\left( \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} \hat T(m) e^{i m \cdot x} \right)(\phi) = \left(\sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} T \left({1 \over (2\pi)^n}e^{-i m \cdot x}\right) \right) (e^{i m \cdot x}\phi).$$

Not sure what to do now. The main issue is that I don't really know what "the distribution $e^{i m \cdot x}$" means. Is it just the distribution with $e^{i m \cdot x}$ as the kernel of the integral, ie

$$S(\phi) := e^{i m \cdot x}(\phi) = \int e^{i m \cdot x}\phi(x)dx?$$

This would then sort me $S(\phi) = (2\pi)^n\hat \phi(-m)$, and so

$$\left( \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} \hat T(m) e^{i m \cdot x} \right)(\phi) = \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} T \left({1 \over (2\pi)^n}e^{-i m \cdot x}\right) (2\pi)^n \hat \phi(-m)$$

$$=T\left(\sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} \left(e^{-i m \cdot x} \hat \phi(-m)\right) \right)$$

$$=T\left(\sum_{m \in \Bbb Z^n} \left(e^{i m \cdot x} \hat \phi(m)\right) \right) = T(\phi),$$

by the Fourier inversion formula for $\phi \in \mathcal S$ (ie a Schwartz function).

Is this right? My issue in trying to work it out has always been that I don't know what form the distribution $e^{i m \cdot x}$ takes, but last night I realised that it probably means the integral form. However, I know that not all distributions arise in such a way - eg, the Dirac $\delta$-function (distribution).

[If it is right, then I've spent ages stuck on (and getting annoyed by =P!) something rather simple!]